# Usage of scheduling policy flags SCHED_BATCH or SCHED_IDLE gives error

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, scheduling

I am trying to use `sched_setscheduler()` to set the scheduling policy of a given process. As per its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html), the available flags are `SCHED_FIFO,SCHED_RR,SCHED_OTHER,SCHED_BATCH,SCHED_IDLE`.

Except for `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE`, I am able to use all the flags and compile my program successfully. However, using, say, `SCHED_BATCH`, I get

```
error: ‘SCHED_BATCH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sched_setscheduler(getpid(),SCHED_BATCH,&param);
```

A sample code to illustrate my problem is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    struct sched_param p;
    p.sched_priority=0;
    sched_setscheduler(getpid(),SCHED_BATCH,&p);
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the man page, I have created an object of typr `sched_param`, set its appropriate `sched_priority` value, and passed it to the function.

My linux kernel version is 4.4.40 and I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. My gcc version is 6.2.0.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE` are Linux specific and are not part of POSIX standard.

Glibc doesn't expose them unless you define `_GNU_SOURCE`. So, do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before including headers.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Could you please point me to some reference so I can read up more about this?

Comment: You can check POSIX doc [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//basedefs/sched.h.html). AFAIC, the additional features/extensions enabled by `_GNU_SOURCE` isn't documented very well. It's mostly found in the individual man pages.